# Paraphrasing in Python

Tags: python, programming

I'm looking for a method that takes some text to paraphrase (i.e. to reword with hopefully the same meaning), and returns one or more paraphrases of it. I've experimented with the method discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508299/paraphrasing-using-nltk-approach-in-python, and wish to run some experiments comparing it to at least one other. I've looked at several on Github, such as [this](https://github.com/paulx3/keras_generative_pg) and [this](https://github.com/iamaaditya/neural-paraphrase-generation) (its code is on a dev branch), but I couldn't find any explanations of how to use them. If you have any suggestions, please include the syntax that calls the paraphrase-generating method, or link to documentation that explains it.

The package needs to be compatible with Python 2.7. It needs to be able to process English text; other languages are not required. (Note: I'm looking for how to *generate* paraphrases; I already have a method of assessing semantic similarity.)